# to change any form of date string using pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime-format

my date time format in excel is 01-12-2010 08:26 (date =01,month =12) when i import that into pandas and change dtype to datetime, month and date both get swapped.I am new to this please help

```
Output of pandas is 
 x .date 
 12
 x. month
 1
```

Excel
`Invoice date = 01/12/2010 08:26`
PANDAS
When import using sales =  pd.read_csv()
sales["InvoiceDate"] = sales["InvoiceDate"].astype("datetime64[ns]")

```
[ln] y["InvoiceDate"].loc[0].
[Out] Timestamp['2010-01-12 08:26:00']

[ln] y["InvoiceDate"].loc[0].day 
[out] 12
```

the output of this should be 1 instead of 12
where i am getting it wrong 
please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas : pandas.to\_datetime() is switching day & month when day is less than 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367656/python-pandas-pandas-to-datetime-is-switching-day-month-when-day-is-less-t)

Answer (score 0):

you can use pd.to_datetime with parameter dayfirst like below

```py
pd.to_datetime("01/12/2010 08:26", dayfirst=True)
```

Comment: glad that helped, plz consider upvote and or mark it as resolved