# Find missing dates between two datetime ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two datetime ranges in pandas dataframe. The resolution is one minute e.g of datetime 2021-03-26 10:23:00.

The dataframe A has the correct datetimes but the dataframe B is missing some datetimes. Is there any way to find which datetimes are missing from dataframe B and create a new dataframe C with the observations of dataframe A but with the datetimes of dataframe B?

Dataframe B

| Dates | Car |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-26 10:23:00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-26 10:24:00 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 10:26:00 | 1 |
| 2021-03-26 10:29:00 | 0 |

Dataframe A

| Dates |
| --- |
| 2021-03-26 10:23:00 |
| 2021-03-26 10:24:00 |
| 2021-03-26 10:25:00 |
| 2021-03-26 10:26:00 |

Answer (score 0):

If there are DatetimeIndex in both DataFrames use:

```
A.index = pd.to_datetime(A.index)
B.index = pd.to_datetime(B.index)

C = A[~A.index.isin(B.index)]
```

If there are dates columns in both DataFrames use:

```
A['Dates']= pd.to_datetime(A['Dates'])
B['Dates']= pd.to_datetime(B['Dates'])

C = A[~A['Dates'].isin(B['Dates'])]

print (C)
                Dates  Car
3 2021-03-26 10:29:00    0
```

Comment: it returns an empty dataframe but there are approximately 122k same dates.

Comment: @Giorgos - Which solution was used?

Comment: @Giorgos - Are datetimes in both?

Comment: I used the second solution.

Comment: Yes both are datetimes

Comment: @Giorgos - So if try `to_datetime` before still not working? Like in changed answer.

Comment: Yes, still not working.  needed to to pd.to_datetime(B.stack()).unstack()) to overcome an error.

Comment: @Giorgos - Can you add some small data sample to question? there is only one column `date` or multiple columns filled by dates?

Comment: I add a small sample of both dataframes. The dataframe B consist of 5 columns but only one column is datetime. Dataframe A consist of just 1 column, the datetime column.

Comment: @Giorgos - Testing and working well with sample data, added output to answer. If not working is possible some another format of data? Why is necessary use `pd.to_datetime(B.stack()).unstack())` here?

Comment: Because I am getting ''ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing'' with just pd.to_datetime(B). The format is datetime64 checked with B.dtypes.

Comment: @Giorgos - Understand. Still not working? Datetimes are converted correctly?

Comment: No its not working, it returns a dataframe now with approx. 40k observations while the different datimes are approx. 14k.

Comment: @Giorgos - hmm, so data related problem. Hard to know what is problem here, with small data sample working solution very well

Comment: find out that pandas confuses days<13 with months. I try to solve it with dayfirst=True argument and several other methods I found in the forum like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367656/python-pandas-pandas-to-datetime-is-switching-day-month-when-day-is-less-t/50372326) but still same.

Comment: @Giorgos - So it means there is part of datetimes swapped? And part not? If yes, it is impossible solve.

Comment: @Giorgos - Because pandas not know if `02-05-2010` is May or February.

Comment: Basically yes, pandas confuses days<13 with months.

Answer (score 0):

```
C = A[~A['date'].isin(B['date'])]
```

You can use it if there are dates columns in each Dataframe