# Pandas check if date is month start

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do this, get a dataframe date and check if date is month_start. If so leave it or swap the day and month part in date

```
    import pandas as pd
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J'],
        'dates': ['01/09/2020','10/01/2020','01/11/2020','01/12/2020','01/02/2021']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'dates'])

df1
```

When i try this,

```
    df2 = df1.assign(dates1=lambda df : pd.to_datetime(df.dates,format="%d/%m/%Y", errors="coerce")) \
.assign(dates2=lambda d : "" if d['dates1'].dt.is_month_start == True else "1")
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

When it try this

```
    df2 = df1.assign(dates1=lambda df : pd.to_datetime(df.dates,format="%d/%m/%Y", errors="coerce")) \
.assign(dates2=lambda d : "" if d['dates1'].dt.is_month_start is True else "1")
```

I dont get the correct answer in my boolean. Can anyone help to tell me how to check if a date is a month start. Also if you could tell me how to swap the month and date it would be great. 10/01/2020 should be swapped to 01/10/2020

Comment: do you really need a column with 1 or '' when start of month, or you just want to swap the month-day when it is not the beginning of the month?

Comment: It's best to convert `'dates'` to a correct datetime format. Calculations, plotting, and methods rely upon having a datetime dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing a whole dataframe in your lambda function, this should do the work and get the output you are expecting:

```
import pandas as pd

dummy_data1 = {
    'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
    'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J'],
    'dates': ['01/09/2020','10/01/2020','01/11/2020','01/12/2020','01/02/2021']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'dates'])

df2['dates1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates'])
df2["dates2"] = ['' if x else "1" for x in df2['dates1'].dt.is_month_start]

print(df2)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an `is_month_start` attribute of pd.DateTimeIndex:

```
df1['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['dates'])    
df1['monthstart'] = df1['dates'].dt.is_month_start
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  id Feature1 Feature2      dates  monthstart
0  1        A        B 2020-01-09       False
1  2        C        D 2020-10-01        True
2  3        E        F 2020-01-11       False
3  4        G        H 2020-01-12       False
4  5        I        J 2021-01-02       False
```

Comment: Hrm.. I think this maybe and x-y problem with date first issues in data.    Maybe this will help your import https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372326/6361531.