# Why the difference in Date format when converting to Datetime in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe such as follows.

```
data = [['250635', 'Comcast Cable Internet Speeds', '22-04-15', '22-Apr-15', '3:53:50 PM'],
        ['223441', 'Payment disappear - service got disconnected', '04-08-15', '04-Aug-15', '10:22:56 AM'],
        ['242732', 'Speed and Service', '18-04-15', '18-Apr-15', '9:55:47 AM'],
        ['277946', 'Comcast Imposed a New Usage Cap of 300GB that punishes streaming.', '05-07-15', '05-Jul-15', '11:59:35 AM']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Ticket #', 'Customer Complaint', 'Date', 'Date_month_year', 'Time'])
```

The dataframe has a Date column which is in the format of dd-mm-yy.

I have converted the object column to datetime using :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

However, this yields a result which have their months and days randomly switched places, such as this,

| Date | Date_month_year |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-04-22 | 22-Apr-15 |
| 2015-04-08 | 04-Aug-15 |
| 2015-04-18 | 18-Apr-15 |
| 2015-05-07 | 05-Jul-15 |

For example, the 1st and 3rd entries are in the correct YYYY-mm-dd order, but the 2nd and 4th have their months and days wrong and are in the order YYYY-dd-mm.

Comment: ...or also [Python Pandas : pandas.to_datetime() is switching day & month when day is less than 13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50367656/10197418)

Answer (score 0):

`to_datetime` accepts a format string, you can use it in your case as:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
```

Comment: To add to this: if you *don't* specify a format, Pandas is forced to guess.